# ¿Como pausar el envió de un formulario PHP hasta que se ejecute una función de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un formulario que enviará los datos completados mediante PHP, pero, antes de ser enviados quiero que mediante JavaScript se cambie el valor de un input hidden en el momento que el usuario clickee el botón de submit. Como si estuviera utilizando asincronía entre javascript y php.

Este es el javascript:

```
    const getCoords = (dir) =>{
        const direccion = dir.replace(/ /g,"+"),
        $mapa = document.querySelector(".mapa");
        
        fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+direccion+'&key=AIzaSyCz8IS8ryD6Z5kn8Rvq6DwObryxnZcBDpo')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
            let latitud = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
            longitud = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng

            document.getElementById("coords").value = "{latitud}, {longitud}"  //aqui cambio el value del input hidden
        })
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    getCoords(document.getElementById("ubication")) //ejecuto la funcion en base a lo que se ha rellenado en otro de los input
})
```

El input hidden es rellenado en base al value que tiene otro de los input.
Con el código tal y como está me dice que mi campo que es rellenado por el hidden es null porque el código javascript no se llega a ejecutar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el formulario "espere" al código javascript antes de ser enviado?

Comment: Ejecuta la función cuando se modifique el campo y no envíes el formulario si el campo oculto está vacío.

Comment: Quizás con un poco más de información podamos ayudarte. Al parecer, ahi no está el formulario (o script) que enviará los datos a tu script en PHP. También podrías enviar la data dentro de esa función getCoords sin usar el formulario, dentro del último `.then()`. BTW la variable `$mapa` (con sigil, heh ) no la usas nunca.

Comment: Coloca el botón `Enviar` del formulario en estado `disabled` por defecto y habilítalo sólo cuando se cumpla la condición que refieres en la pregunta. Si eso depende del cambio de un `input` sería cuestión de asignar un `onchage` listener a ese input, hacer la verificación y habilitar el botón si procede. Lo que no se entiende mucho es que al parecer cambias el valor del input dentro de la petición fetch que lanza el mismo botón de envío de formulario, que quieres hacer depender de lo mismo que él lanza ¿? ¿No es más bien un error de planteamiento lo que hay en tu caso?

Comment: @A.Cedano, la lógica en la petición AJAX es correcta, porque actualiza un campo oculto (cords) con los resultados obtenidos al enviar el valor de otro campo (ubicacion). El error está en querer hacer la petición hasta que se envíe el formulario, como bien sugieres, debería hacerse cuando se modifique la ubicación, con el evento que mejor le acomode (change, blur, input, etc.) y mucho mejor si sigue tu sugerencia completa, deshabilitando el botón hasta obtener un valor adecuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas cancelar el evento para aplicar las modificaciones que deseas y luego continuar con su ejecución. Para ello debes vincular el evento a un listener y posteriormente en el callback aplicar la función `.preventDefault()` al evento que llega como argumento del callback, esto te permitirá detener la acción y tener control total.

No temas, luego puedes reanudar la llamada para que el proceso sea invisible para el usuario sin necesidad de hacer clic dos veces sobre el botón de enviar.

Te dejo un ejemplo referencial de lo que quieres hacer.

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
   // Detiene el evento 
   event.preventDefault()
   // Acá haces lo que quieres
   let hidden = document.querySelector('#id')
   console.log("Original input hidden id", hidden.value)
   hidden.value = 2
   console.log("Input hidden now is", hidden.value)
   // Acá vuelves a gatillar la acción del formulario
   form.submit()
});
```

```html
<h5>Mi formulario</h5>
<form action="http://whatever.tutancamon" method="GET">
  <input id ="id" type="hidden" value="100" name="id"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="write it" name="something"/>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```